# how sinch callback works

Tags: android, callback, sinch

i want a create a android paid calling app using sinch.
sinch includes a callback API to get details of call.
i wanted to use this but no idea how to. 
i read the documentation. but it is not enough

my question is,

1. what are the requests to the server.?
2. how can i find what to what country the call is going on ?
3. how can i restrict calls based on the account balance in our database

**Note:**
i can generate the userid for calling it is a 15 digit string i will use it as username to connect a call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Configure a calling callback url in the dashboard for you app
2. Implement your backend details can be found here: https://www.sinch.com/docs/rest-apis/api-documentation/#callingcallbackapi
3. When you get the ICE event, you will get who is calling, look up the balance in your database, if the user doesnt have balance create a hangup action instead of ConnectPSTN.

Comment: in app to app calling how do we know call has been ended,so we can deduct the appropriate amount

Comment: For APP to Phone you will get a Callback, for app to app, either report back in the client on call did end or crunch CDR that we can drop on your AWS for automatic processing.

Comment: @cjensen can you please have a look on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60978486/sinch-callback-api-hangup-in-ice-event