# Sinch CallBack API : Hangup in ICE event

Tags: c#, voip, sinch, sinch-rest-api

I had place call between two Android devices which is running successfully. Now I want to implement Callback Rest API because of some server side decision before place call. As given in this [image](https://sinch.github.io/docs/voice/voice-rest-api/images/callbackevents.png), **ICE** event fire and developer backend respond **SVAML** response.

Now I want to simply **Hangup Call**, for this I had done following code :

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public SvamletModel MakeCall(CallbackEventModel model)
    {
        var sinch = SinchFactory.CreateCallbackResponseFactory(Locale.EnUs);
        var reader = sinch.CreateEventReader();
        var evt = reader.ReadModel(model);

        var builder = sinch.CreateIceSvamletBuilder();

        SvamletModel svaml = builder.Hangup().Model;

        return svaml;
    }
```

but call still placed. I had also write action class under SvamletModel but same response.

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public SvamletModel MakeCall(CallbackEventModel model)
{
    var sinch = SinchFactory.CreateCallbackResponseFactory(Locale.EnUs);
    var reader = sinch.CreateEventReader();
    var evt = reader.ReadModel(model);

    var builder = sinch.CreateIceSvamletBuilder();



    SvamletModel svaml = builder.Build().Model;


    SvamletActionModel actionModel = new SvamletActionModel();
    actionModel.Name = "Hangup";
    svaml.Action = actionModel;

    return svaml;
}
```

Note I had followed all steps given in [Callback API](https://developers.sinch.com/docs/voice-rest-api-callback-api#section-actions) and https://developers.sinch.com/docs/further-securing-your-sinch-calling-functionality-app-with-rest-api with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting return type from `SvamletModel` to `string` is working.

So I have changed

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public SvamletModel MakeCall(CallbackEventModel model)
    {
        var sinch = SinchFactory.CreateCallbackResponseFactory(Locale.EnUs);
        var reader = sinch.CreateEventReader();
        var evt = reader.ReadModel(model);

        var builder = sinch.CreateIceSvamletBuilder();

        SvamletModel svaml = builder.Hangup().Model;

        return svaml;
    }
```

to

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public string MakeCall(CallbackEventModel model)
    {
        var sinch = SinchFactory.CreateCallbackResponseFactory(Locale.EnUs);
        var reader = sinch.CreateEventReader();
        var evt = reader.ReadModel(model);

        var builder = sinch.CreateIceSvamletBuilder();

        SvamletModel svaml = builder.Hangup().Model;

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(svaml, Formatting.Indented);

        return json;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi your code looks correct, can you capture and send here the HTTP response your backend is sending as response of the ICE POST?
Also add the callID for call.

Sinch Voice & Video Team

Comment: It return SvamletModel object whose equivalent json is
{
  "instructions": [],
  "action": {
    "name": "Hangup"
  }
}

call ID : f696e9c0-b949-493f-a326-777d660f9119

Comment: did you check ?

Comment: ** You are returning this: **
{"Data":"Sinch.ServerSdk.Calling.Models.SvamletModel","Message":null,"StackTrace":null,"Result":200}


** Instead of: **
{"Data":"{\"action\":{\"name\":\"hangup\"}}","Message":null,"StackTrace":null,"Result":200}

Comment: after return JSON string its working please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/61061136/991085

Comment: Now the question is ACE event not calling, can you please answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61046499/sinch-answered-call-event-callback-ace-not-called