# Sinch Answered Call Event Callback (ACE) not called

Tags: sinch, sinch-rest-api

I have added a Callback in Sinch portal to handle app to app calls via our server. When a call reaches the Sinch platform, the system makes a POST request to our server's calling callback URL i.e. **Incoming Call Event Callback (ICE)** called.

In response to ICE event our server response it as

```
{
  "instructions": [],
  "action": {
    "name": "connectMXP"
  }
}
```

and callee receive incoming call notification. When Callee pick-up call the call get connected but it doesn't request to our server's callback URL, i.e. ACE event not called.

But as given in [Answered Call Event Callback (ACE)](https://developers.sinch.com/docs/voice-rest-api-callback-api#section-answered-call-event-callback-ace)

This callback is made when the call is picked up by the callee (person receiving the call). It is a POST request to the specified calling callback URL.

So the question is what is required to receive ACE event callback, is there anything missing which should be enable at Sinch side or our server side in code ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App2APp calls only support ICE and DICE events.  If you authorized the Caller to Call the Callee user, why do you need another event notification? As the calls are mostly peer2Peer based we currently do not support ACE or PIE events for Data calls.